# Report the mean number of characters in Corpus document

Tags: r, rstudio, mean, text-mining

So I have a corpus setup reading bunch of text file with paragraphs in them.

```
    library('tm')
my.text.location <- "C:/Users//.../*/"
apapers <- VCorpus(DirSource(my.text.location))
```

Now I need to find the mean of the characters in each text. Running a
 `mean(nchar(apapers), na.rm =T)` results in a very weird output, more than the number of characters. 
Any other way to get the mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't supply a reproducible example, but `rowMeans(sapply(apapers, nchar))` will return the mean number of characters over all documents. "Content" is the column you need.

A longer version is running a sapply over the corpus counting the number of per document. Transpose this data and turn it into a data.frame. The data.frame will contain two columns, content and meta. Content is the one you need. Taking the mean of the content column will give you the average number of characters in a document. The advantage of this is that you have the table in case you need to report the numbers.

```
# your code
my_count <- data.frame(t(sapply(apapers, nchar)))
mean(my_count$content)
```

Reproducible example using the crude dataset:

```
library(tm)
data("crude")
crude <- as.VCorpus(crude)

# in one statement
rowMeans(sapply(crude, nchar))
    content    meta 
    1220.30  453.15

# longer version keeping intermediate results.
my_count <- data.frame(t(sapply(crude, nchar)))
mean(my_count$content)
[1] 1220.3

my_count
    content meta
127     527  440
144    2634  458
191     330  444
194     394  441
211     552  441
236    2774  455
237    2747  477
242     930  453
246    2115  440
248    2066  466
273    2241  458
349     593  492
352     621  468
353     591  445
368     629  440
489     876  445
502    1166  446
543     463  447
704    1797  456
708     360  451
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks but trying the above code gives me `argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA` error. I think I need to use the as.numeric function?

Comment: what does `nchar(apapers)` return?

Comment: `content    meta   dmeta`
`2122736       6       6`

Comment: Also if instead of characters I have to work with words, I just change `nchar` to `length`?

Comment: No, changing to `length` will not work. Counting words is more for after you turned everything in a DocumentTermMatrix. Then you can use nTerms. Or using the quanteda package which is better suited for this, `quanteda::ntoken(quanteda::corpus(crude))`

Comment: Okay and after that I just find mean from `mean()` function?